# What is the appropriate Kotlin Flow to use here while creating an app with compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-stateflow

The following is the activity class.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels { MainViewModelProvider() }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            StateExampleTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    val state by viewModel.viewStatePublisher.collectAsState()

                    when (state) {
                        is ViewState.Failure -> {
                        }
                        ViewState.InProgress -> {
                        }
                        is ViewState.Success -> {
                            val event = (state as ViewState.Success).data
                            Greeting(event, viewModel)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(event: Event, viewModel: MainViewModel) {
    Column {
        Text(text = "Hello ${event.data}!")
        Button(onClick = {
            viewModel.updateState(event)
        }) {
            Text(text = "Click")
        }
    }

}
```

And the view model is

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _viewStatePublisher: MutableStateFlow<ViewState> =
        MutableStateFlow(ViewState.Success(Event(0)))
    val viewStatePublisher: StateFlow<ViewState> = _viewStatePublisher

    fun updateState(event: Event) {
        event.data = event.data + 1
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _viewStatePublisher.emit(ViewState.Success(newEvent))
        }
    }
}

class MainViewModelProvider : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MainViewModel::class.java)) {
            return MainViewModel() as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

my View state is handled by

```
sealed class ViewState {
    data class Success(val data: Event) : ViewState()
    data class Failure(val message: String) : ViewState()
    object InProgress : ViewState()
}
```

and the event class is

```
data class Event(var data: Int)
```

With the above, I'm unable to update my UI as I click the button and I need to know if `StateFlow` is the right way to achieve this?

You may suggest changing the `Event` to the following

```
data class Event(val data: Int)
```

And update the `updateState()` method to

```
fun updateState(event: Event) {
        val newEvent = event.copy(data = event.data + 1)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _viewStatePublisher.emit(ViewState.Success(newEvent))
        }
    }
```

But I want the `data` to be `mutable` and update the `state` when `data` changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do goes against language design and `StateFlow` can'
t tell that the underlying data has changed, so it won't notify any subscribers with the new data.

I'd go with with using an `immutable` in the data class, why do you need it to be mutable/var?

Comment: I have a huge tree and don't want to keep copying each after the change so want to just have a `mutable` `var` and update thee `UI`. And don't want to go against the design language, so I'm asking what will the appropriate one to use instead of `StateFlow`?

Comment: if you want to optimize, split that single `ViewState` class into multiple smaller chunks or primitives. That way you can update only the part which you need.
For handling loading, success and error states you can also create a separate `StateFlow`